# Bug in Emacs 29.0.60 or is there a way to prevent moving the Emacs position on restart?

Tags: desktop

Emacs allows to store the state of its GUI in a .desktop file which on next start of Emacs restores its last state. It should preserve its size, position and arrangement of the tabs and windows (it does it as good as it can, i.e. not all and not preserving all window line tabs), but it restores its position on the desktop not the right way.

See the images below which are showing the original position, than the position after one restart, the position after 6 restarts and the position after 11 restarts:

[image: 00] Original position

[image: 02] after one restart

[image: 06] after six restarts

[image: 11] after eleven restarts.

After the eleventh restart the Emacs GUI has arrived at the leftmost top position of the screen and each next restart does not change the position anymore. So it is no more moving as before a bit to the left and even smaller bit to the top drifting slowly left and up.

As I can't reproduce this bug on another configuration below the .emacs.desktop file content which produced the described behavior:

```
;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; lexical-binding:t; coding: utf-8-emacs; -*-
;; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Desktop File for Emacs
;; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Created Wed Mar 29 15:05:05 2023
;; Desktop file format version 208
;; Emacs version 29.0.60

;; Global section:
(setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (25636 14209 358494 694000) (desktop . "208") "neo@OoO" nil nil ((((minibuffer . t) (undecorated) (override-redirect) (font . "-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-regular-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1") (border-width . 0) (internal-border-width . 0) (child-frame-border-width) (right-divider-width . 22) (bottom-divider-width . 0) (vertical-scroll-bars . right) (horizontal-scroll-bars . t) (foreground-color . "#5f5f5f") (background-color . "#dbeedb") (mouse-color . "black") (border-color . "black") (screen-gamma) (line-spacing) (left-fringe . 10) (right-fringe . 10) (no-special-glyphs) (scroll-bar-foreground) (scroll-bar-background) (menu-bar-lines . 1) (tab-bar-lines . 1) (tool-bar-lines . 0) (title) (wait-for-wm . t) (tool-bar-position . right) (inhibit-double-buffering) (icon-type . t) (auto-raise) (auto-lower) (cursor-type . box) (scroll-bar-width . 16) (scroll-bar-height . 16) (alpha) (alpha-background) (no-focus-on-map) (no-accept-focus) (fullscreen) (visibility . t) (use-frame-synchronization) (skip-taskbar) (z-group) (display-type . color) (background-mode . light) (cursor-color . "#5f5f5f") (font-parameter) (sticky) (shaded) (environment) (tabs (current-tab (name . "emacs_eww-pckg_view-http-www-internet-web-PageTextAndImages-inWindowBuffer.py") (explicit-name)) (tab (name . "*ielm*") (explicit-name) (time . 1680060825.9886034) (ws ((min-height . 4) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 3) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 1) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 96) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 72) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 24) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*ielm*" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 79) (start . 1)) (prev-buffers ("*scratch*" 1 144)))) (tab (name . "*shell*") (explicit-name) (time . 1680061303.5174878) (ws ((min-height . 4) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 3) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 1) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 96) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 72) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 24) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*shell*" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 79) (start . 1)) (prev-buffers ("*python*" 1 13) ("*ielm*" 1 79)))) (tab (name . "*python*") (explicit-name) (time . 1680061993.4876225) (ws ((min-height . 8) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 8) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 2) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 192) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 192) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 48) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) vc (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 448) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 19) (normal-height . 0.5) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*python*" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 14) (start . 1)) (prev-buffers ("test.txt" 1 1) ("*eshell*" 1 34) ("*python*" 1 162))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 456) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 19) (normal-height . 0.5) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*ielm*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 79) (start . 1)) (prev-buffers ("*eshell*" 1 34))))) (tab (name . "*eshell*") (explicit-name) (time . 1680061066.9566364) (ws ((min-height . 4) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 3) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 1) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 96) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 72) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 24) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*eshell*" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 34) (start . 1)) (prev-buffers ("test.txt" 1 1) ("*eshell*" 1 34)))) (tab (name . "test.txt") (explicit-name) (time . 1680061021.8446264) (ws ((min-height . 4) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 3) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 1) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 96) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 72) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 24) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "test.txt" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))) (tab (name . "*Messages*") (explicit-name) (time . 1680060486.0934253) (ws ((min-height . 4) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 3) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 1) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 96) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 72) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 24) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*Messages*" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 2744) (start . 858)))) (tab (name . "*scratch*") (explicit-name) (time . 1680089840.7782388) (ws ((min-height . 8) (min-width . 10) (min-height-ignore . 6) (min-width-ignore . 5) (min-height-safe . 2) (min-width-safe . 2) (min-pixel-height . 192) (min-pixel-width . 120) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 144) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 60) (min-pixel-height-safe . 48) (min-pixel-width-safe . 24)) vc (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 448) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 19) (normal-height . 0.5) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)) (next-buffers "smooth-scrolling.el") (prev-buffers ("*scratch*" 1 1) ("smooth-scrolling.el" 4371 5186) (".emacs" 8833 9491) ("*Messages*" 1 2955))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 456) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 19) (normal-height . 0.5) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*Buffer List*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))))) (dnd-root-window-position) (last-focus-update . t) (frameset--id . "ACFD-F9FA-323F-F2FA") (frameset--mini t . t) (modeline . t) (unsplittable) (icon-name) (display . ":0") (explicit-name) (user-size . t) (height . 38) (width . 153) (left . 41) (top . 61)) ((min-height . 28) (min-width . 60) (min-height-ignore . 22) (min-width-ignore . 40) (min-height-safe . 7) (min-width-safe . 12) (min-pixel-height . 672) (min-pixel-width . 720) (min-pixel-height-ignore . 528) (min-pixel-width-ignore . 480) (min-pixel-height-safe . 168) (min-pixel-width-safe . 144)) vc (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 904) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 38) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (hc (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 240) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 10) (normal-height . 0.2654867256637168) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 1356) (pixel-height . 240) (total-width . 113) (total-height . 10) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.7243589743589743) (buffer "emacs_eww-pckg_view-http-www-internet-web-PageTextAndImages-inWindowBuffer.py" (selected . t) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 44) (start . 2)) (prev-buffers ("*scratch*" 1 1) ("*Messages*" 2508 2508) (".emacs" 9485 9491) ("smooth-scrolling.el" 5666 5699))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 516) (pixel-height . 240) (total-width . 43) (total-height . 10) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.27564102564102566) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))) (hc (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 504) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 21) (normal-height . 0.5575221238938053) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 228) (pixel-height . 504) (total-width . 19) (total-height . 21) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.1217948717948718) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (vc (pixel-width . 492) (pixel-height . 504) (total-width . 41) (total-height . 21) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.2628205128205128) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 492) (pixel-height . 120) (total-width . 41) (total-height . 5) (normal-height . 0.23809523809523814) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (hc (last . t) (pixel-width . 492) (pixel-height . 384) (total-width . 41) (total-height . 16) (normal-height . 0.7619047619047619) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 204) (pixel-height . 384) (total-width . 17) (total-height . 16) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.41463414634146345) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (vc (last . t) (pixel-width . 288) (pixel-height . 384) (total-width . 24) (total-height . 16) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.5853658536585366) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 288) (pixel-height . 240) (total-width . 24) (total-height . 10) (normal-height . 0.625) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)) (prev-buffers ("*Messages*" 484 868) ("*scratch*" 1 1))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 288) (pixel-height . 144) (total-width . 24) (total-height . 6) (normal-height . 0.375) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))))) (vc (pixel-width . 228) (pixel-height . 504) (total-width . 19) (total-height . 21) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.1217948717948718) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 228) (pixel-height . 288) (total-width . 19) (total-height . 12) (normal-height . 0.5714285714285714) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 228) (pixel-height . 216) (total-width . 19) (total-height . 9) (normal-height . 0.42857142857142855) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))) (vc (last . t) (pixel-width . 924) (pixel-height . 504) (total-width . 77) (total-height . 21) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.4935897435897436) (combination-limit) (hc (pixel-width . 924) (pixel-height . 360) (total-width . 77) (total-height . 15) (normal-height . 0.7142857142857143) (normal-width . 1.0) (combination-limit) (vc (pixel-width . 672) (pixel-height . 360) (total-width . 56) (total-height . 15) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.7272727272727273) (combination-limit) (leaf (pixel-width . 672) (pixel-height . 120) (total-width . 56) (total-height . 5) (normal-height . 0.33333333333333337) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (leaf (pixel-width . 672) (pixel-height . 192) (total-width . 56) (total-height . 8) (normal-height . 0.5333333333333333) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 672) (pixel-height . 48) (total-width . 56) (total-height . 2) (normal-height . 0.13333333333333333) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 252) (pixel-height . 360) (total-width . 21) (total-height . 15) (normal-height . 1.0) (normal-width . 0.2727272727272727) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 924) (pixel-height . 144) (total-width . 77) (total-height . 6) (normal-height . 0.2857142857142857) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))))) (leaf (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 96) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 4) (normal-height . 0.10619469026548672) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1))) (leaf (last . t) (pixel-width . 1872) (pixel-height . 64) (total-width . 156) (total-height . 3) (normal-height . 0.07079646017699115) (normal-width . 1.0) (buffer "*scratch*" (selected) (hscroll . 0) (fringes 10 10 nil nil) (margins nil) (scroll-bars nil 2 t nil 1 t nil) (vscroll . 0) (dedicated) (point . 1) (start . 1)))))])
(setq desktop-missing-file-warning nil)
(setq tags-file-name nil)
(setq tags-table-list nil)
(setq search-ring '(#("insert" 0 6 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("margin" 0 6 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("dbeedb" 0 6 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("d" 0 1 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("scroll" 0 6 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("good-s" 0 6 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("smooth-" 0 7 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("rainbow-d" 0 9 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil)) #("rain" 0 4 (isearch-case-fold-search t isearch-regexp-function nil))))
(setq regexp-search-ring nil)
(setq register-alist '((48 . #("neo@OoO:/A$ python\nPython 3.11.2 (main, Feb 27 2023, 02:34:32) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux\nType \"help\", \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n>>> exit\nUse exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit\n>>> exit()\nneo@OoO:/A$ python\nPython 3.11.2 (main, Feb 27 2023, 02:34:32) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux\nType \"help\", \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n>>> exit()\nneo@OoO:/A$ " 0 12 (font-lock-face (comint-highlight-prompt comint-highlight-prompt) fontified t) 12 18 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 18 19 (fontified t) 19 85 (fontified t) 85 156 (fontified t) 156 160 (fontified t font-lock-face (comint-highlight-prompt comint-highlight-prompt)) 160 164 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 164 165 (fontified t) 165 205 (fontified t) 205 209 (font-lock-face (comint-highlight-prompt comint-highlight-prompt) fontified t) 209 213 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 213 215 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 215 216 (fontified t) 216 228 (font-lock-face (comint-highlight-prompt comint-highlight-prompt) fontified t) 228 234 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 234 235 (fontified t) 235 301 (fontified t) 301 372 (fontified t) 372 376 (fontified t font-lock-face (comint-highlight-prompt comint-highlight-prompt)) 376 380 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 380 382 (help-echo "mouse-2: insert after prompt as new input" mouse-face highlight comint--fontify-input-inhibit-fontification t font-lock-face comint-highlight-input fontified t) 382 383 (fontified t) 383 395 (font-lock-face (comint-highlight-prompt) fontified t)))))
(setq file-name-history '("/A/o/test.txt" "~/.emacs.d/elpa/smooth-scrolling-2.0.0/smooth-scrolling.el" "/home/neo/.emacs.d/elpa/smooth-scrolling-2.0.0/smooth-scrolling.el" "/A/o/emacs.stackexchange.com_standard-comment-text.py" "~/.emacs_._hide" "~/.emacs.bak" "/A/o/emacs_goto-address-mode_make-internet-http-www-web-links-URL-clickable.py" "/A/o/emacs_eww-pckg_view-http-www-internet-web-PageTextAndImages-inWindowBuffer.py" "/duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=emacs+tramp&ia=web" "/A/o/emacs_font-face_definition_codeExample.py" "/home/neo/.emacs" "~/.emacs.d/dired+/find-dired+.el" "~/.emacs" "~/.emacs.d/dired+/find-dired+.el" "/A/o/emacs_install-downloaded-package_about.py" "~/.emacs.d/dired+/find-dired+.elc" "~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+/find-dired+.el" "~/.cache/.fr-7ejFZD/Emacs-Elisp-Programming-master/Elisp_Snippets.org" "~/.cache/.fr-rjJHlN/Emacs-Elisp-Programming-master/codes/test.cpp" "~/.cache/.fr-t1Ngam/Emacs-Elisp-Programming-master/Makefile" "~/.cache/.fr-PH1F22/Emacs-Elisp-Programming-master/README.org" "/home/neo/.emacs.d" "/A/o/emacs_lnx-gui_txtEditor_about_STARThere.py" "~/.emacs"))

;; Buffer section -- buffers listed in same order as in buffer list:
(desktop-create-buffer 208
  "/A/o/emacs_eww-pckg_view-http-www-internet-web-PageTextAndImages-inWindowBuffer.py"
  "emacs_eww-pckg_view-http-www-internet-web-PageTextAndImages-inWindowBuffer.py"
  'python-mode
  '(eldoc-mode font-lock-mode goto-address-mode tab-line-mode)
  44
  '(30 nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((tab-width . 8) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 25636 14192 867490 100000) (buffer-file-coding-system . undecided-unix))
  '((mark-ring (44))))

(desktop-create-buffer 208
  "/home/neo/.emacs"
  ".emacs"
  'emacs-lisp-mode
  '(nlinum-mode font-lock-mode eldoc-mode tab-line-mode)
  9491
  '(9491 nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((buffer-display-time 25636 9431 629799 925000) (buffer-file-coding-system . undecided-unix) (truncate-lines . t))
  '((mark-ring (9747 9673 8889 9897 9799 9799 9869 9774 9748 9427 9372 9747 9747 9747 9673 9491))))

(desktop-create-buffer 208
  "/home/neo/.emacs.d/elpa/smooth-scrolling-2.0.0/smooth-scrolling.el"
  "smooth-scrolling.el"
  'emacs-lisp-mode
  '(font-lock-mode eldoc-mode tab-line-mode)
  5699
  '(4515 nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((buffer-display-time 25636 9210 61893 551000) (buffer-file-coding-system . prefer-utf-8-unix))
  '((mark-ring (6404 7386 4515 4594 679 4515 4843 7386 5665 6404 5705 5699))))

(desktop-create-buffer 208
  "/A/o/emacs_goto-address-mode_make-internet-http-www-web-links-URL-clickable.py"
  "emacs_goto-address-mode_make-internet-http-www-web-links-URL-clickable.py"
  'python-mode
  '(eldoc-mode font-lock-mode goto-address-mode tab-line-mode)
  63
  '(45 nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((tab-width . 8) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 25636 8863 405788 366000) (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix))
  '((mark-ring (137 45 137 3))))

(desktop-create-buffer 208
  "/A/o/emacs.stackexchange.com_standard-comment-text.py"
  "emacs.stackexchange.com_standard-comment-text.py"
  'python-mode
  '(font-lock-mode eldoc-mode tab-line-mode)
  504
  '(504 nil)
  nil
  nil
  '((tab-width . 8) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 25636 8857 87264 197000) (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix))
  '((mark-ring (1 504))))

(desktop-create-buffer 208
  "/A/o/emacs_font-face_definition_codeExample.py"
  "emacs_font-face_definition_codeExample.py"
  'python-mode
  '(font-lock-mode eldoc-mode tab-line-mode)
  32
  '(1 t)
  nil
  nil
  '((tab-width . 8) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 25636 14192 821856 755000) (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-8-unix))
  '((mark-ring (33 146 2 146 1 320 110 1))))
```

**I have already reported this as a bug.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is:

** YES, it is clearly a bug.**

But ... can this "bug" be easily reproduced?

In the specific case of given configuration it does occur, but I was not able to reproduce it on another example.

Below the parts which change from restart to restart in the Emacs .desktop file. I am comparing the lines (with the line number given before the colon) of the original state and after four (4x) restarts:

```
4 : ;; Crea : 5:05 20
4 : ;; Crea : 8:01 20
9 : (setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (25636 14209 358494 694 
    : (height . 38) (width . 153) (left . 41) (top . 61))
9 : (setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (25636 14385 957164 975
    : (height . 38) (width . 153) (left . 13) (top . 41))
28 :   '((tab-width  : 192 867490 1000
28 :   '((tab-width  : 346 531244 5000
40 :   '((buffer-displ : 431 629799 925000
40 :   '((buffer-displ : 549 566579 798000
52 :   '((buffer-disp : 210 61893 551000
52 :   '((buffer-disp : 328 10503 575000
64 :   '((tab-width .  : 863 405788 366000
64 :   '((tab-width .  : 981 361212 311000
76 :   '((tab-width . : 857 87264 197000
76 :   '((tab-width . : 975 50251 621000
88 :   '((tab-width .  : 192 821856 755000
88 :   '((tab-width .  : 346 483415 817000
```

There is a difference in values for left and top properties. According to this values each restart moves Emacs 7 pixels to the left and 5 pixels to the top.

The best work around would be probably to permanently disable Emacs

`Menu -> Options -> Save State between Sessions` ,

create a directory (for example: `~/.emacs.d/desktops/config-01`) and use then explicit

```
    M-x desktop-save
```

to save a configuration and

```
    M-x desktop-change-dir
```

to load the .desktop file from the specified directory.

Another option could be to change the saved wrong values on each start of Emacs starting Emacs from a shell script which subtracts 7 and 5 from `left` and `top` values as this is what goes wrong probably due to miscalculation of some border widths.

**But ... if it is apparently hard to reproduce the bug, the simplest way to handle this situation is to just ignore it, because it does not occur in any other tested configurations.**

Comment: I suggest a bug report: this is down in the weeds of the interaction between Emacs and the Desktop Environment/Window Manager. It looks as if some `frame` function gets something slightly wrong, but it would require an expert to figure out what.

Comment: I don't know: I'm no expert.

Comment: @NickD : see my updated answer for details of this Emacs "bug". I have checked out a little bit about how do I file a bug report? And failed to find out how. With around 3000 bugs ... many older than one year. I am giving up on the idea of reporting a bug. .

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: OK ...  I have reported it adding the .desktop file to the question. Can you reproduce the issue using this file?